# How to select multiple fields from Json Play framework?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, playframework, scala-collections

I am trying to access the data from REST-API and parse the response (json) using play framework. Below is my response look from REST Call.

```
[
{"time":"2018-01-01","query":"select..","service":"sql"},
{"time":"2018-01-01","query":"select..","service":"sql"},
{"time":"2018-01-01","query":"select..","service":"sql"}
]
```

I would like to select time , service and make it as a row as like below,

```
2018-01-01,sql
2018-01-01,sql 
2018-01-01,sql
```

I used \ to get time but it return List Buffer.

```
val json = Json.parse(response_from_rest)
println((json \\ "time"))
```

Could any one help how can I select multiple fields into single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
json.as[List[JsValue]].map(row => 
  (row \ "time").as[LocalDate] -> (row \ "service").as[String]
)
// List[(LocalDate,String)]
```

The the `.as` method transforms the json into a list and the `.map` method applies replaces each object with a tuple.

Comment: In order to improve your answer, please add some explanation as to how it solves the problem.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Which part warrants an explanation?

Comment: The part that causes your answer to be automatically flagged as low-quality.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Yes, which part is that? (I presume an answer should aim to satisfy humans, not machines)

Comment: Perhaps a comment regarding why the .map or the => operator is needed in order for the code to work, pursuant to the guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  As for whether the answer needs to satisfy both humans and SO's algorithm, I presume the answer is both, but it's not my algorithm.

Comment: @EricHauenstein I updated with an explanation (mostly noise since i don't think the example warranted it). Both => and .map are very basic scala, I mean do I also need to explain types? or strings? in an answer asking about a JSON library? Algorithms should work for humans, not the other way around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169785/discussion-between-eric-hauenstein-and-alvaro-carrasco).

Answer (score 0):

```
val parsedJson = json.validate[Seq[JsValue]].get
 parsedJson.map(x => x.\("times") +","+x.\("service")).foreach(println)
```

Used Validate and iterated oved through map function.